# Showing SCHEDULED entries few days in advance

Tags: org-mode, org-agenda

How can I easily show SCHEDULED entries few times before it comes up given date?

Let's say I have to leave my car for repairs on monday, but I would like to have a reminder one day and one week earlier so I don't plan anything requiring a car or something.

I know I could use diary remind for

`life:       Reminder: Only 2 weeks until Car repairs`

But I don't know how to connect this with SCHEDULED entry. 
Any ideas on how to do this? Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: `SCHEDULED` means: I plan to work on this on such and such a date and I don't want to worry about it beforehand. `DEADLINE` means: this has to be done by such and such a date, so I need reminders beforehand to make sure that I finish it by then. See [Deadlines and scheduling](https://orgmode.org/manual/Deadlines-and-scheduling.html#Deadlines-and-scheduling) in the manual. That's why you want to use `DEADLINE` in this case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of `SCHEDULED` use `DEADLINE`, which provides a warning before the date.  You can configure the warning time in the timestamp.  For example:

```
* Car repair
DEADLINE: <2018-01-07 -2w>
```

Will provide a warning 2 weeks in advance. The global default for the warning period comes from the variable `org-deadline-warning-days`.